# Direct method to open `Print Preview and Print` window , other than using Send Keys?

Tags: excel, vba

I seek for a direct method to open `Print Preview and Print` window , other than using Send Keys. 
 `Application.SendKeys ("%FP~")`

[image]

Comment: @Raymond Wu , yes it answer.I did my best search before posting my question.kindly advice, should I delete my question or do what?

Comment: Your question has been marked as duplicate so I think it's ok to let it be.